# Validate zip code using just first 4 digits

Tags: magento, csv

I'm using table rates to assign shipping costs in Magento.
Our zip codes are in the following format: XXXX-XXX. Is there any "easy" way I can change the validation so that 1234-234 is assigned the same shipping cost as 1234-678 without doing it explicitly? 
I would like to fill the tablerates.csv file like this:

```
Country,Region/State,"Zip/Postal Code","Order Subtotal (and above)","Shipping Price"
US,*,1234,20,5
```

and the system would assign 5 as the shipping cost to 1234-234, since 1234 is contained within 1234-234.

I'm imagining a simple change from "if clientzip = csvzip" to "if clientzip like 'csvzip%" somewhere in Magento's files...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a workaround. My country didn't have regions set in the database, so I added the three relevant regions to my country (in terms of shipping costs).

INSERT INTO `db_magento`.`directory_country_region` (
`region_id` ,
`country_id` ,
`code` ,
`default_name`
)
VALUES (
NULL , 'CountryCode', 'RegionCode', 'Region Name')

Now the system automatically forces filling out the "State/Province" field.